# Issue with the npm dev server (JQUERY) Symfony 4

Tags: jquery, symfony, npm

I'm trying to add [select2](https://select2.org/) with my dev servers node package manager but I have always get a weird issues and I feel completely lost ... 
I already installed yarn and I already installed the select2 dependencies with npm.

I don't want to use a jquery module so I use externals
That is the weird issue i was talking about (i'm on ubuntu 18.04)

```
npm run dev-server

> @ dev-server /var/www/html/my_project_name
> encore dev-server

Running webpack-dev-server ...

ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                        18:59:21

This dependency was not found:

*  jquery in ./node_modules/select2/dist/js/select2.js

To install it, you can run: npm install --save jquery
```

And of course this file exist on the good folder !

Here is the end of my webpack.config.js

```
var config = Encore.getWebpackConfig();

config.externals.jquery = 'jQuery'

module.exports = config
```

And my app.js

```
require('../css/app.css');

require('select2');

$('select').select2()

console.log('Hello Webpack Encore! Edit me in assets/js/app.js');
```

I tried to solve my problem for 4 hours with no results. Thanks for reading this to the end!

Comment: When you say you don't want to use a JQuery module it is confusing. It is a dependency of `select2` as the error states. JQuery must be added before `require('select2');`

Comment: I didnt add  Jquery before because i load jquery from a CDN

Comment: It would be helpful if you included that in your question. According to the error it's not recognized.

Comment: @EternalHour is right. How does NPM know that? It is a dependancy. Add it. You can always still choose what your application uses.

Comment: Thanks you guys for your support, how can i make it know by NPM ?

Comment: Give this a try. [Specifying dependencies and devDependencies in a package.json file](https://docs.npmjs.com/specifying-dependencies-and-devdependencies-in-a-package-json-file) You can also do it [this way](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-add-dependencies) if you don't want to install the package.

Comment: It is weird, select2 s appropriately registered in package.json ... The second command didnt change anything :o I'm sure i'm doing smthing wrong

Comment: JQuery needs to be in package.json since it's a dependency.